# grep and show all the lines within two occurrences

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a data file laid out like this --

```
# stream 0
....
....
.... N lines of data
# stream 1
....
....
.... M lines of data
```

here **M != N**.

I am trying to dump the data that belongs only in `#stream 0` --

```
cat data.txt | grep "# stream 0$" -A N
```

but the thing is that I know neither the length of N nor M.

I need some commands that will show all the data after the match (`# stream 0`) until it hits the next string `# stream`

Can I do it with grep? How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use awk, it has this functionality available with an easy syntax:

```
 awk '/# stream 0/,/# stream 1/' data.txt
```

And please note me avoiding a useless use of `cat` :-)

The `/startpattern/,/endpattern/` syntax evaluates to true for every line between and including the start- and endpattern. The default action is to print the line, so you don't need to tell awk to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`AWK` can do that very easily

```
awk '/# stream 0/,/# stream 1/' input
```

will print  all line matching between the two pattern

```
# stream 0
....
....
.... N lines of data
# stream 1
```

If you want to use `grep`, then you can remove the newline character and `grep` the result

```
cat input | tr -d '\n' | grep -o '# stream 0.*# stream 1'
```

provided that it will produce a clutterd output with all the newlines removed

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on using `grep`, you can do this:

```
grep -A 999999 "stream 0" file | grep -B 999999 "stream 1"
```

You can do it with `sed` too:

```
sed -ne '/stream 0/,/stream 1/p' file
```